# Simple JQuery Drag and Drop not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to JQuery stuff ,but this is ridiculous ,i cant do drag and drop work

.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">      
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="drag">Drag me</span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my drag js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#drag').draggable();
});
```

By the way, do i need to have JQuery UI to make drag and drop stuff?

Thank you

Comment: Check your javascript console by hitting f12 in your favorite browser. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes you should be using jquery-ui as [draggable is part of that framework](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please make sure the resource mentioned is in the correct location ("js" directory?). Here is [your example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzrm32s/).

Comment: @tutuDajuju it is in the correct directory but still not working locally

Comment: Well, you mentioned that you use a `php` file, so I assume you are running your application with a php server... can you provide more info on your environment? You'll have to set up your machine to serve static files (js, css, jpg...), some people use a route ([tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/taking-advantage-of-phps-built-in-server/)), otherwise, refer to your server's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the libraries in the correct order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag.js"></script>
```

Your custom code (drag.js) should be last, after jquery and jquery-ui have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The draggable() function requires jQueryUI to work. After including jQueryUI your code works fine.

```
$('#drag').draggable();
```

http://codepen.io/tejzpr/pen/raXqKz

Answer (score 0):

I would use cdn to save on speed and resources, and also be sure that you have a working copy. The order was probably your issue, however, as people mentioned above.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first load UI script and use it after.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag.js"></script>
```

Important: don't forget jQuery 2.* browser compatibility:
https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x
It doesn't support IE 8 or earlier!